# how to parse Json objects which are nested in spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

i have a json file with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- demo: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dateOfBirth: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- email: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- emergencyContacts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- phone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- relationship: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- phones: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- home: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mobile: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- registered: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- product: string (nullable = true)
 |-- releaseDate: string (nullable = true)
```

**i want to parse the emergencyContacts array so as to get the names of the contacts**

i have reached till the persons struct using:

```
val df =sqlContext.read.json("file:///home/training211/test/cjson1.json").toDF();
df.registerTempTable("df");
df.printSchema();
val person = df.select("person");
person.registerTempTable("person");
person.printSchema();
person.show();
```

if i want to go further it always gives an error as :
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'persons.emergencyContact                                                                                        s' given input columns: [person];

also tried doing:

```
val arrayFlatten = df.select($"person.emergencyContacts".getItem(0))
```

which gives me

```
+---------------------------+
|person.emergencyContacts[0]|
+---------------------------+
|       [Jane Doe,888-555...|
+---------------------------+
```

but this is not the result i want

Any help is appreciated

Comment: when you try `df.select($"person.emergencyContacts")`, what you got? can you update your question?

Comment: done! Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below.

```
df.select($"person.emergencyContacts").show
```

If you want to get the `phone`, you can do something like this.

```
df.select($"person.emergencyContacts.phone").show
```

Or you can iterate the emegencyContacts array to get the phone and name details. Look for Scala array iteration.

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(person, emergencyContacts)`;

i'm getting this error with the solution provided

Comment: @KaranKaushal: Remove the * at the end, updated the answer.

Comment: @KaranKaushal: Also, look into this http://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2016/01/30/processing-json-data-with-sparksql/

Comment: your updated answer gives me the whole emergencyContacts array .is it possible to further flatten and get the details like names and phone etc seperately?

Comment: @KaranKaushal: Updated the answer.

Comment: @KaranKaushal: You can look into this blog for nested json array http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.in/2015/06/reading-json-data-in-spark-dataframes.html

Comment: Thanks that did it :)

Comment: Do you have the  `df.select($"person.emergencyContacts.phone")` for Python equivalent?  Because using $ for Python will give invalid syntax errors when running in PySpark.